# Strange things happening when I am updating mysql database from my form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that users use to update items. The form contains input fields such as iten name, item price, quantity etc.
Now, the form is updating, but it is duplicating the item description in the database. 
This is the item description adds ends up as:

> This is the item description This is the item description.

Is there a way to only update text that has changed? The form is built in php.

Comment: update tblname set columnname='newvalue' where uniqueid='id'

Comment: ask some programmer to fix your form handler code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this once if you are using mysql

there is 2 solutions for it...

1. If you want to update value of field if new value changed from existing one. then run query for every field separately one by one of form

   ```
   update tbalename set fieldname = 'fieldvalue' where  table_id = "unique id value" AND fieldname != "fieldvalue";
   ```
2. else

   ```
   update tbalename set fieldname1 = 'fieldvalue1', fieldname2 = 'fieldvalue2',fieldnamenth = 'fieldvaluenth' where  table_id = "unique id value"
   ```

It will update all fields value ....

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for replying. Ths database is now updating correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be meaningful if u post your code.. But this is the syntax of mysql update query

```
UPDATE table SET field = 'yourvalue' WHERE id = 'id value'
```